# Laravel: No puedo visualizar imágenes al subir la web a mi Hosting

Tags: laravel, linux, hosting, cpanel

Tengo una web desarrollada en Laravel, en local puedo visualizar todo el contenido de la web sin problemas, he subido la web a mi hosting (Linux) en la carpeta del dominio donde quiero tener la web (es un hosting compartido con varios dominios), configuré la base de datos y modifiqué el archivo .htaccess. La web carga, sin embargo no visualiza el logo ni las imágenes almacenadas en public/images.

alguna idea de a que se debe esto? agradezco cualquier orientación

Destacar que la web que menciono no se encuentra en la carpeta public_html de mi hosting, puesto que ya hay otra web ocupando esa carpeta (es un Shared hosting), la web se encuentra en una carpeta carpeta-dominio.com fuera de la carpeta public_html.

Este es el método que estoy utilizando para hacer el llamado de las imágenes `src="{{asset('images/imagenes/home/imagen.jpg')}}"`

Ya me he fijado y no existen errores de sintaxis debido a distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Al inspeccionar en el navegador y chequear los errores, esto es lo que recibo en mención de las imágenes:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

naturalmente, las imágenes no están siendo encontradas.

Por último, aclarar que no estoy intentando subir imágenes a mi web, las imágenes ya se encuentran almacenadas en la carpeta public/images y simplemente estoy tratando de hacer llamado de dichas imágenes.

Comment: Primero edita la pregunta y agrega el código correspondiente (con el que subes y muestras la imagen), y una captura de pantalla del error en consola.

Comment: Hola Lash, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a que hagas [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas cómo funcionamos y de paso ganes tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Respecto a tu pregunta, revisa que los nombres de las imágenes estén escritos tal cual en el código, muchos desarrollos en local se hacen en Windows, que no distinge entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, y cuando se suben a un hosting (los cuales son casi todos en ambiente Linux) sí que afecta cómo esté escrito.

Comment: Saludos, muestra el codigo que como muestras una de las imagenes, de acuerdo a eso veremos que es lo que pasa ya que trabajar en local no es lo mismo para subirlo a la web, se debe de modificar ciertas cosas al subir a un hosting

Comment: Estás en Windows? de ser así, fíjate en los Namespaces de tus controladores, y que coincidan las mayúsculas.

Comment: Hola y gracias a todos la colaboración. He editado la consulta para dar más detalles según sus sugerencias. Como menciono, el servidor es Linux en efecto, más no tengo errores de distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (tanto carpetas, archivos y códigos están en minúsculas). Por otro lado aclarar que no estoy intentando subir imágenes a mi web, las imágenes ya se encuentran almacenadas en la carpeta public/images

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es un enlace simbolico desde `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` tal como dice la documentacion de laravel, que la puedes ver [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk).

El comando para lograr esto es `php artisan storage:link`, lo que hace q tendras que tener artisan en tu hosting compartido

Personalmente lo hacia con este comando

```
ln -s ../storage/app/public ./public/storage
```

Comment: Aún no he probado con tu sugerencia Samir , en cuanto lo intente te lo haré saber

Comment: Samir, tengo el mismo problema de las imágenes que no e visualizan al subir mi proyecto de laravel a un servidor, implementé tu sugerencia con el comando php artisan storage:link, y me creo la ruta que mencionas, pero al momento de mostrar una foto utilicé esta ruta, pero no me funciona: <img src="{{asset('storage/app/public').'/'.$tecnico->fotoPerfil}}" alt="" width="200"> El error que me aparece es:
http://flare.com/storage/app/public/uploads/k9jLttOr4dnI3jNSH3B1XsUjEFe6LrwFZu3rTczy.jpeg
404 not found